# Как добавить элемент к словарю через ключ заключенный в переменной?

Tags: python, словари, dict

У меня есть множество S мне необходимо создать словарь в котором будет отображаться ребра между вершинами из множества S. Проблема заключается в том, что когда я добавляю значение в словарь, это значение добавляется к каждому ключу, а не только к одному.

```py
def linkGraph(inputWords, s):
  adjacencyList = dict.fromkeys(s, [])
  for i in s:
    for j in s:
      if i != j:
        for k in range(len(inputWords)):
          word = i + inputWords[k] + j 
          if word in inputWords:
            adjacencyList[i].append(j)
  return adjacencyList
```

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

К примеру:

```py
d = {}.fromkeys([i['house'] for i in cards], [])
d = {k: [i for i in cards if i['house'] == k] for k, v in d.items()}
```

И сейчас:

```py
print(d)
```